# What determines how much experience a champion receives?

Tags: league-of-legends

How is experience gain determined when killing minions and/or other champions?  Does last hitting change experience?  Distance from minions?  Is experience for champion kills handled the same way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [LoL Forums](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=120762)

For minions on Summoner's Rift:

- Melee minions are 64 exp +5 every 3 minutes
- Ranged minions are 32 exp +3 every 3 minutes
- Rider minions are 100 exp +7 every 3 minutes

Time starts from game start, not from the initial minion spawn.  Minions increase in exp if they spawn *after* the "x" minute mark.

Last hitting doesn't change the experience gained.  Neither does distance - you either get the experience or you're too far away.  That's why zoning is so effective.

From [LoL Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_(champion)):

> Killing an enemy champion rewards a player with an amount of experience determined by the level of the champion slain. The experience gained is equal to 75% of the total experience required for a champion to go from the slain champion’s current level to the next level up. In other words, if a level 7 champion is slain, the total experience gained is 75% of the total experience required for a champion to go from level 7 to level 8, or 862.5 experience points. The experience reward will be increased if there is a positive level difference between champions (e.g. a level 5 champion killing a level 7 champion) and decreased if the level difference is negative.

EDIT:
Additionally, you have to factor in +exp masteries and runes, if you have either of them or both.

In addition, when more than 1 champion is sharing experience, 10% extra experience is split among all champions.

- Two champions each gain 55%.
- Three champions each gain 36.7%.
- Four champions each gain 27.5%.
- Five champions each gain 22%.

Comment: You're missing how having multiple people nearby reduces the XP each champion receives (solo lane levels faster vs. duo)

Comment: @NickT Right.  Spaced that out.  I'm usually playing support, so I'm almost always duo.  Thanks!

Comment: I find there is nothing about sharing experience in lol wikia, so would you please add it to the wiki?

Answer (score 4):

To add to the above poster's information: don't forget that Zilean's passive, Heightened Learning, will also increase your team's experience gain by 8%.

Comment: Also, Nidalee has a hidden passive: Nearby allied champions gain +5 experience every 5 seconds if they are a lower level than her.